# How to solve the range of `t` satisfying the condition

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

On the polynomials of $f(x)= x^3 - 7 x^2 - (t^2 - 6) x + 5t^2 + 4 t$, what value can `t` take so that all roots of $f(x)= x^3 - 7 x^2 - (t^2 - 6) x + 5t^2 + 4 t$ are greater than `0`.

```
   f[x_] := x^3 - 7 x^2 - (t^2 - 6) x + 5t^2 + 4 t;
   SolveAlways[Implies[f[x] == 0 && f[y] == 0, x > 0 && y > 0], {x, y}]
```

But the code above can't find the range of `t` (the answer is $-\frac{4}{5}< t<0$). what can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that `Root[Function[x, poly], 1]` is equal to the minimum real root of poly, and use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce):

```
Reduce[Root[Function[x, x^3 - 7 x^2 - (t^2 - 6) x + 4 t], 1] > 0, t] //N
```

> -5.86346 < t < 0.

Comment: Thank you very much. And can you use the function `SolveAlways` to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Not[Resolve[
   Exists[x, x <= 0 && x^3 - 7 x^2 - (t^2 - 6) x + 5 t^2 + 4 t == 0], 
   Reals]] // Simplify
```

Or

```
Resolve[ForAll[x, x^3 - 7 x^2 - (t^2 - 6) x + 5 t^2 + 4 t == 0, 
  x > 0 ], Reals]
```